# Python 3: splitting by 3rd delimiter

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to split the data by the third delimiter while including that delimiter in the output.

## Code

```
text = 'sitting on a couch sitting on a chair sitting on a bench'

splitText = text.split('sitting')[1]

print(splitText)
```

## Outcome

on a couch sitting on a chair sitting on a bench

## Desired outcome

sitting on a bench

## Notes

- SPLIT FUNCTION DOES NOT INCLUDE 'sitting' IN OUTCOME WHEN USING IT AS A DELIMITER
- 'sitting' MUST BE INCLUDED IN THE OUTCOME

Comment: mistake, I changed it to text

Comment: The outcome isn't what you say it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'sitting' + text.split('sitting')[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split by `space` before `sitting`.

```
x="sitting on a couch sitting on a chair sitting on a bench"
print re.split(r"\s(?=\bsitting\b(?:(?!\bsitting\b).)*$)",x)[1]
```

Or `split on 0 width assertion` which is not there in `re` module but there in `regex` module.

```
import regex
x="sitting on a couch sitting on a chair sitting on a bench"
print regex.split(r"(?=sitting)",x,flags=regex.VERSION1)[3]
```

Or use `findall`.

```
x="sitting on a couch sitting on a chair sitting on a bench"
print re.findall(r"(sitting.*?(?=sitting|$))",x)[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex :

```
r'(sitting.*){2}'
```

This regex will match a text that is contain the word `sitting` 2 time.then you can split the `text` with `re.split()` :

```
>>> text = 'sitting on a couch sitting on a chair sitting on a bench'
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(sitting.*){2}',text)
['', 'sitting on a bench', '']
```

You can get the result with a generator expression and `next` :

```
>>> next(i for i in re.split(r'(sitting.*){2}',text) if i)
'sitting on a bench'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = 'sitting on a couch sitting on a chair sitting on a bench'
splitText = re.findall('sitting.*?(?= sitting|$)', text)

if len(splitText) >= 3:
    print(splitText[2])
```

Eric: "This splits by regexes rather than splitting by word index." - there was "regex" tag in question, it you want to use only indexes - you can use one following samples:

```
text = 'sitting on a couch sitting on a chair sitting on a bench'
delim = 'sitting'
text[text.find(delim, text.find(delim, text.find(delim)+1)+1):]
```

or

```
def X(text, delim, n, pos=0):
        idx = text.find(delim, pos)
        if idx >= 0 and n > 0:
                return X(text, delim, n-1, idx+1)
        if n > 0:
                return ""
        if idx > 0:
                return text[pos-1:idx]
        return text[pos-1:]


text = 'sitting on a couch sitting on a chair sitting on a bench'
print(X(text, 'sitting', 3))
```